# Programa JAVA que pida N numeros enteros y lo muestre con el siguiente orden; el primero, el último, el segundo, el penúltimo, el tercero, etc

Tags: java, matrices

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
System.out.print("Introduce 10 números separados por espacios: ");
    int[] matriz = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        int numeros = in.nextInt();
        matriz[i] = numeros;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(matriz[i] + " ");
        for (i = 9; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

He hecho un primer bucle para recoger todos los números, y en los dos siguientes es donde no consigo hacer el intercambio, pues se me muestra el primer y el último número pero a partir de ahí se genera un bucle infinito.

Comment: No necesitas el bucle interno; cuando el primer elemento es 0+0 y el último es 9-0.

Comment: Cuando se itera, se usa un bucle para recorrer cada nivel de un array... un array de una única dimensión se recorre con un bucle, uno de dos (`matriz[n][m]`) se recorre con dos bucles... etc. Obviamente si haces dos bucles y por encima les pones la misma variable, en uno le dices ++ y en el otro --... eso es un bucle infinito, claro. Si anidas bucles debes usar diferentes variables para que no se afecten uno a otro. Aunque como te han dicho ya en varias ocasiones, no necesitas anidar bucles aquí, basta con uno!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con un solo for que itere la mitad del tamaño del array podes acceder a la posición i (la de la iteración) y a la 9-i (para la primera iteración será 9-0=9, para la segunda iteración con i=1, será 9-i, es decir 9-1=8, la penúltima, y así sucesivamente).

```
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length/2; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(matriz[i]); 
            System.out.print(matriz[9-i]);   
        }
```

Comment: Recomiendo que en vez de matriz[9-i] lo cambies por matriz[matriz.length-i], así si el usuario cambia el tamaño funcionara igualmente.